# Why are the regression estimates different from the chosen of reference level?

Tags: r

I have posted this question in [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173529/why-are-the-regression-estimates-different-from-the-chosen-of-reference-level) for few days but nobody has offered an answer yet, so I would like to move it here looking for some hints.

Suppose I have a continuous outcome y and two factorial predictors with two levels of each of them:

```
set.seed(123)
y<-rnorm(100, 100, 10)
drug.ab<-factor(sample(c("A", "B"), 100, T), levels=c("A", "B"))
drug.ba<-factor(drug.ab, levels=c("B", "A"))
smoke<-factor(sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, T), levels=c("No", "Yes"))

#Model1:
coef(summary(lm(y~drug.ab*smoke)))
                     Estimate Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)       100.7484158   2.065091 48.7864379 1.465848e-69
drug.abB            0.9030541   2.796146  0.3229639 7.474250e-01
smokeYes           -0.8693598   2.632484 -0.3302431 7.419359e-01
drug.abB:smokeYes   0.8709116   3.746684  0.2324487 8.166844e-01

#model2:
coef(summary(lm(y~drug.ba*smoke)))
                       Estimate Std. Error       t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)       101.651469922   1.885161 53.9218978856 1.377147e-73
drug.baA           -0.903054145   2.796146 -0.3229638818 7.474250e-01
smokeYes            0.001551843   2.666021  0.0005820821 9.995368e-01
drug.baA:smokeYes  -0.870911601   3.746684 -0.2324486531 8.166844e-01
```

My question is why the estimate for `smokeYes` are different from model1 and model2? why aren't just different in flip of sign like `drug.baA` and the interaction term?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a cross-post and the original post was posted to the correct site.

Comment: The point of stack overflow is for people to look for answers rather thank keep strict posting rules.

Comment: No the point is to provide answers to good, on-topic questions. And your question is not on-topic here, but on CV.

Answer (score 1):

An R-coded explanation; When regressors are all categorical, the coefficients are completely explained by examining means within categories. Just use the extremely useful functions: `tapply` and `interaction`:

```
> tapply( y, interaction( drug.ab, smoke) , mean)
     A.No      B.No     A.Yes     B.Yes 
100.74842 101.65147  99.87906 101.65302
```

The Intercept is the A.No value for the first case and the B.No value in the second case. The other coefficients are just differences from those base-cases, and since you changed the baseline, the differences cannot simply be sign-flips. If you used a different set of contrasts you might be referencing the test to a "grand mean" but R uses "treatment contrasts" which might be different than the defaults of softwares you might have used in the past.